# How to get information from another intent?

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am new on android and I don't understand how the Broadcast Receiver works. In my app I have intent that extends Broadcast Receiver, and also I have xmlFile with editTextPreference. How could I get the text on the xml file into the Broadcast Receiver intent?

This is my xmlFile(res/xml/Prefs.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference 
        android:title="EditText"
        android:key="name"
        android:summary="Enter your name"
        />
    </PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add information to an intent like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("preferencesText", textYouMeanToSend);
```

and in your broadcast reciever you can call to get the string:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("preferencesText", somedefaultvalue);
```

**EDIT**

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

A Broadcastreceiver will always receive a callbock on its `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` callback, so you dont have to call `getIntent()`, as you already have it at that point

so, move your retrieving code to onReceive and change it to:

```
intent.getStringExtra("preferencesText", somedefaultvalue);
```

Comment: it says-"The method getintent() is undefined for the type SMSReceiver"